# Completely Regular Topological Space and Measure Theory

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Here is the statement...

Suppose that $(X,\tau)$ is a comletely regular topological (I think the lecturer requires X to be Hausdorff too.), and that E is a dense linear subspace of $(C_{b}(X),\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$.
Let $\sigma (E)$ be the smallest $\sigma$-field which makes all the functions in E measurable. Then $\sigma (E)$ is the Baire $\sigma$-field.

Why does E have to be a linear space?

Comment: Which makes *all* the functions *on* E measurable? Really?

Comment: @Chris Good spot. I meant in E.

Comment: So $\sigma(E)$ is supposed to be a $\sigma$-field on $X$?

Comment: As Chris points out, the word "continuous" is missing.

Comment: @Chris Yes. Sorry I didn't make that clear!

Comment: In fact, for the purpose of this question I don't see why we even need that X is completely regular and Hausdorff either.

Comment: @rustyracketman Because $C_b(X)$ could be trivial (e.g. only constant functions) if we don't assume any separation axioms (even if we only assume regular and Hausdorff).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma How does that prevent the statement being true?

Comment: @rustyracketman It must be needed somehow: if $X$ is a $T_3$ space with only constant real-valued functions (these exist) then $C_b(X)$ is just the set of constant functions, and taking $E$ equal to $C_b(X)$ then $\sigma(E)$ is the trivial $\sigma$-field (as constant functions are always measurable) with only 2 members, and this is surely not the Baire $\sigma$-field for $X$.

Comment: The Baire $\sigma$ field is by definition the smallest $\sigma$ field for which all the elements in $C_{b}(X)$ are measurable. So if you take E = $C_{b}(X)$ then the statement in trivially true. There is no contradiction.

Comment: @rustyracketman OK, that was not my definition though. The Baire $\sigma$-field is the $\sigma$-field generated by the compact $G_\delta$ subsets of $X$, at least this is what I learned. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_set, and in that case my space $X$ (the only-constant functions space) could have way more Baire sets than just the 2.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thankyou. Ah, in that case the property of a Completely regular Hausdorff space shows that the Baire $\sigma$ field is equivalent to what I thought the definition was.

Subsequently, I believe I need the result: (that in this setting above)

The smallest $\sigma$-field making all bounded continuous functions on $X$ measurable is equal to the the smallest $\sigma$-field making all continuos functions on $X$ measurable.